# ActiveRecord change column default value (not working)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-migrations

I've got a `companies` table in my database with two columns (`size` and `state`) that I wish to add default values to. Currently there is no default value and the columns are not set to `null: false`. I've tried using the `update_column` and `update_column_default` methods as outlined in the [docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/change_column_default), but neither seems to be doing anything. I'm able to run the migration but there are no changes to the table.

I've tried `update_column` like so:

```
class AddDefaultValuesToCompanies < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
        def up
            change_column :companies, :state, :string, default: 'MA'
            change_column :companies, :size, :string, default: '1-10'
        end

        def down
            change_column :companies, :state, :string, default: nil
            change_column :companies, :size, :string, default: nil
        end
    end
end
```

I've also tried using `update_column_default` like so:

```
class AddDefaultValuesToCompanies < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
        def up
            change_column_default(:companies, :state, 'MA')
            change_column_default(:companies, :size, '1-10')
        end

        def down
            change_column_default(:companies, :state, nil)
            change_column_default(:companies, :size, nil)
        end
    end
end
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: The migration you have will change the column defaults but will not update existing data...

Comment: I do not believe it is proper syntactically to wrap a `change` block around a `down` or `up` block. I do not know if this is at least partially responsible for your issue. What is being output when you run `rake db:migrate`?

Comment: Wow, can't believe I missed that. It was the change block from when I ran `rails g migration`. Completely forgot to remove that.

Answer (score 0):

Your migration will only change the default value for newly created records.  I would write a rake task to update the existing values in the DB.  Use something like

```
Companies.where(state: "").map{|c| c.update_attribute(state: "ma")
```